# Contains "Make A Wish" in a combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access 2013, I have a combo box that allows user to select a RunType. If the run type contains "..Make A Wish" I want to set a value to True in a True/False field to True if the selection contains "Make A Wish" in it.

```
If Me.ActiveControl = "##Make A Wish" Then
MsgBox "Contains Make a wish"
Else
MsgBox "Not make a wish"
End If
```

Testing this code and it isn't working :(
Any help is appreciated!
Dianna

Comment: Doesn't work is always difficult to solve for someone who wants to help... What happens? What Control is the ActiveControl? Should it test if the Selection in the Combobox contains "Make A Wish (then why not assign every Entry a number and test for the according value(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use `like` method:

```
If lcase(me.textfield.value) Like "*make*a*wish*" Then
```

Comment: Why do you use `*` within the check string? This would find something like `I will make my homework, a text about coding. I wish I was already done!`

Comment: This is just an example how to use 'like' method, pattern can be anything you want

Answer (score 1):

Check for a part of a string like this:

```
if instr(teststring, testpattern) then ...
```

You Probalby will need to also make everything Upper (or lower)-case:

```
if instr(ucase(me.textfield.value),"MAKE A WISH") then
```